# How to include an if-statement inside a PHP echo?

Tags: php, html, if-statement, echo

```
 for ($i=0; $i<$total_questions_for_exam; $i++) {

        $question_id= $question_and_answers[$i]['question_id'];
        $numberofanswersperquestion = count_answers_belongToOne_questionNew($question_id);
        //die(var_dump($question_id)); 
        $student_answer_per_question = retrieve_student_result ($_SESSION['user_id'], $_GET['quiz_id'], $question_id);
         echo '   <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-datatable table-hover">
                    <tbody>

                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align: left;" width="100%"><strong>Question '. ($i+1) .'</strong></td> 
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align: left;" width="100%">' . $question_and_answers[$i]['question_name'] .'</td>
                        </tr>



                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align: left;" width="100%" class="warning"><em>Question Not attempted</em><br><strong>Correct Answer is</strong><br>' . $numberofanswersperquestion[0]['answer_name'] . '</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td style="height: 5px;" width="100%">&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                        <td style="height: 5px;" width="100%">&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                    </table>';

 }
```

Hi guys I have this for loop, what I am trying to do is, only print this

```
<tr>
    <td style="text-align: left;" width="100%" class="warning"><em>Question Not attempted</em><br><strong>Correct Answer is</strong><br>' . $numberofanswersperquestion[0]['answer_name'] . '</td>
</tr>
```

based on an if statement. But how can put that if statement inside that echo ??

I have tried this way, by

```
' . if() {} . '
```

but I couldn't get it to work this way.

this is what I want inside the if statement

```
if($student_answer_per_question === '' || '') {
 <tr>
    <td style="text-align: left;" width="100%" class="warning"><em>Question Not attempted</em><br><strong>Correct Answer is</strong><br>' . $numberofanswersperquestion[0]['answer_name'] . '</td>
</tr>
}
```

I hope I have explained the problem in detail and I appreciate any help from you guys. Thanks

Comment: you can split your echo statement

Comment: `if($student_answer_per_question === '' || '') {` `''` [will always be falsy](https://3v4l.org/dPjXK)

Comment: So this is how it looks currently, https://gyazo.com/cad66adb763d2ffc23b71b5a9c500231

Comment: if statement is working fine now but that else statement is not getting called for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can temporarily define a variable to store your output.

```
$output = '<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-datatable table-hover">
                <tbody>

                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: left;" width="100%"><strong>Question '. ($i+1) .'</strong></td> 
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: left;" width="100%">' . $question_and_answers[$i]['question_name'] .'</td>
                    </tr>';
if(condition)
{
$output .= '             <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: left;" width="100%" class="warning"><em>Question Not attempted</em><br><strong>Correct Answer is</strong><br>' . $numberofanswersperquestion[0]['answer_name'] . '</td>
                    </tr>';
}
$output .=              '<tr>
                        <td style="height: 5px;" width="100%">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                    <td style="height: 5px;" width="100%">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
                </table>';
```

Comment: after making some change, this is currently how it is, https://gyazo.com/cad66adb763d2ffc23b71b5a9c500231

Comment: would you have any idea, why that else not getting called ?? that if statement is working now, but that else echo is not getting called at all

Comment: Thanks I fixed it, it was that if statement, should have been like this if($student_answer_per_question == '')

Answer (score -1):

Create a variable, before the echo statement for example **$statement** and use PHP Shorthand If/Else, something like this

```
$statement = ($student_answer_per_question == '')? "Option 1" : "Option 2";
```

Now you can just print the **$statement** within your echo statement, as

```
echo "blah blah $statement blah blah";
```